# Spring addFormatters not called of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, converters

I'm trying to implement a converter in a `Spring` Boot app but for some reason my override of `addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry)` is never called. What's confusing is that other overridden methods are called, `addInterceptors` works just fine. Security is enabled for this app.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.web"})
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @Autowired
  private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

  @Inject
  private TenantIdentifierInterceptorAdapter multiTenancyInterceptor;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    logger.info("adding interceptor");
    registry.addInterceptor(multiTenancyInterceptor);
  }

  //THIS IS NOT CALLED
  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {
    logger.info("adding converters"); 
    formatterRegistry.addConverter(new StringToPersonConverter());
  }

  private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {"classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
      "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"};

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS)
        .setCachePeriod(3600).resourceChain(true).addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
  }

}
```

For some reason if I add this code to the file the formatter code is hit, but I get an error "A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling" and the app won't compile.

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new       ResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setBasename("messages");
return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: Adding `@EnableWebMVc` disables the Spring Boot auto configuration for it (so you might now have disabled parts of Spring Boot you weren't aware of). Actually your configuration is reconfiguring things that are already configured by default (like the static resources). But you are basically making things to complex, Spring Boot auto registeres converters and formatters, just make your `StringToPersonConverter` a bean and Spring Boot will configure the rest). So basically remove `@EnableWebMvc` and replace `addFormatters` with an `@Bean` for `StringToPersonConverter`.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. I've removed `@EnableWebMvc` and the method `addFormatters`, then added `@Bean
  StringToPersonConverter stringToPersonConverter() {
    return new StringToPersonConverter();
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured a bean with super class WebMvcConfigurationSupport?
If you did so, it will disable WebMvcAutoConfiguration Bootstrap.
Check this code:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(
    type = Type.SERVLET
)
@ConditionalOnClass({Servlet.class, DispatcherServlet.class, WebMvcConfigurer.class})
@ConditionalOnMissingBean({WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class})
@AutoConfigureOrder(-2147483638)
@AutoConfigureAfter({DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class, ValidationAutoConfiguration.class})
public class WebMvcAutoConfiguration {
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but did you try to remove `@EnableWebMvc` annotation from the class? Because [according to documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration) it shouldn't be there:

> If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features, and you just want to add additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view controllers etc.) you can add your own @Configuration class of type WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but **without** @EnableWebMvc.

Comment: Still doesn't work :( I wasn't sure if I needed '@EnableWebMvc' or not either but I've seen a lot of documentation with it so I left it in. Removing it doesn't work. Thanks for the response brother!

Answer (score 0):

M. Deinum's comment was the answer. I've removed `@EnableWebMvc` and removed the method `addFormatters`, then added:

```
@Bean
StringToPersonConverter stringToPersonConverter() {
  return new StringToPersonConverter();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but this stopped working. I'm getting the error "no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

Answer (score -1):

I have solved a similar error

[EnableWebMvc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
@Import(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableWebMvc {
}
```

[DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.html)

```
@Configuration
public class DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    private final WebMvcConfigurerComposite configurers = new WebMvcConfigurerComposite();

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public void setConfigurers(List<WebMvcConfigurer> configurers) {
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(configurers)) {
            this.configurers.addWebMvcConfigurers(configurers);
        }
    }

    //...

    @Override
    protected void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        this.configurers.addFormatters(registry);
    }

    //...

}
```

[WebMvcConfigurationSupport](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html)

```
public class WebMvcConfigurationSupport implements ApplicationContextAware, ServletContextAware {

    //...

    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        FormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
        addFormatters(conversionService);
        return conversionService;
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to add custom {@link Converter}s and {@link Formatter}s.
     */
    protected void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    }

    //...

}
```

My custom config with multiple [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org.springframework/web.servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) implements [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html)

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers)
    {
        argumentResolvers.add(new RequestTenantResolverComposite(conversionService));
    }
}
```

The method will not be called if the FormattingConversionService implements ConversionService bean created before [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) injected.

I solved my question using [Lazy](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) annotion for ConversionService with spring verions 4.3.6.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please include any relevant code in your answer. Linking images to code is bad idea.